# Dynamic Number of Lists

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to create a dynamic number of lists in C#, but I'm not sure what to write. Here is what I have:

```
List<List<ISpoolerObject>> writer = new List<List<ISpoolerObject>>();

for(int z=0; z < numPartitions; z++)
    writer[z] = new;
```

I know the top part is right, but I'm just not sure what to put on the right of the new inside the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `Add` method to add new item into `List` instance:

```
List<List<ISpoolerObject>> writer = new List<List<ISpoolerObject>>(numPartitions);

for(int z = 0; z < numPartitions; z++)
{
    writer.Add(new List<ISpoolerObject>());
}
```

Just for fun - it can be done in different way as well:

```
List<List<ISpoolerObject>> writer = Enumerable.Range(0, numPartitions).Select(x => new List<ISpoolerObject>()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Add` method to add lists to `writer`.

```
for(int z=0; z < numPartitions; z++)
{
    writer.Add(new List<ISpoolerObject>());
}
```

or you can use `Range` method

```
List<List<ISpoolerObject>> writer = Enumerable.Range(0, numPartitions)
                                              .Select(i => new List<ISpoolerObject>())
                                              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know ahead of time how many items you are going to put into the `List<T>` type then you should use the constructor which accepts the capacity

```
List<List<ISpoolerObject>> writer = new List<List<ISpoolerObject>>(numPartitions);
```

This makes the `List<T>` more efficient when adding elements later on.  As for the actual loop to add new elements use the `Add` method

```
for(int z = 0; z < numPartitions; z++) {
  writer.Add(new List<ISpoolerObject>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have won't work, as you aren't initializing the List of Lists with any elements. You'll have to `Add()` the `new List<ISpoolerObject>()` that you want for every partition.

```
List<List<ISpoolerObject>> writer = new List<List<ISpoolerObject>>();

for(int z = 0; z < numPartitions; z++)
{
    writer.Add(new List<ISpoolerObject>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking it down into multiple steps

```
for (int z = 0; z < numPartitions; z++)
{
    // what do we want to add here?
    // a list of IspoolerObject.
    // so let's create that first.
    List<ISpoolerObject> aSingleList = new List<ISpoolerObject>();

    // now we add it to the list of lists
    writer.Add(aSingleList);
}
```

Note you will have to deal with populating the individual lists somewhere down the road.